# Azure Pipeline to trigger for two browsers every Thursday 5pm IST

Tags: parameters, yaml, azure-pipelines, schedule

Currently working on a Azure DevOps pipeline setup which needs to be scheduled every Wednesday and needs to run with two browser parameters

This is what my YAML code currently looks like:

parameters:

- name: browser
  display Name: Select browser to run the suite
  default: chrome
  values:

  - chrome
  - safari
  - edge
- name: Environment
  display Name: Environment to run the suite
  default: TEST
  values:

  - TEST
  - QA
  - DEV

I can select the browser and environment when i click on Run Pipeline.

But is there any way to schedule and run the Pipeline passing the parameters safari and edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through an object and print out each string in the object. For example:

```
parameters:
- name: browser
  type: object
  default:
  - chrome
  - safari
  - edge

- name: Environment
  type: object
  default:
  - TEST
  - QA
  - DEV

steps:
- ${{ each p in parameters.browser}}:
  - script: echo ${{ p }}
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful? Is your issue solved?